# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing. When post to API

Tags: typescript, httpclient, angular6

I got this error when I try to do a POST action to backend API by using HttpClient in Angular 6. I got this error:"CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing".

The Temporary solution for me is to install the CORS extension on Google Chrome browser.

What is the best solution to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable your backend services to accept requests from your angular 6 website. This thing is called [CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). By default your website url is `http://localhost:4200`

The way to do this depends on what language / framework you are using to develope your backend services.

Here is an example in SpringBoot to configure CORS. It is only for development purpose, you should restrict access at the minimum, turning wildcards into your needed data (for example you url, as discussed early).

```
@Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }




@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
                .csrf().disable()

                // TODO adjust CORS management
                .cors().and()

                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

                // don't create session
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter(userDetailsService(), jwtTokenUtil, tokenHeader);
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. The backend service is built on the JAVA platform.